# AWS S3 Glacier ACL - Public read access to Glacier objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm experimenting with S3's Glacier storage class right now and haven't been able to find the answer to this. I'm trying to restore a file and send a public download link to someone outside the organization who doesn't have access to the AWS account. The file I tested was uploaded to Glacier with no public read permissions so the public URL doesn't work after restoring (permission denied). Is there any way to change the Glacier's object permissions from within the S3 console after it has been uploaded? It appears that I can set the ACL for an object when I upload, but once a file has been uploaded to Glacier I don't have the ability to modify the ACL.

A little more info: A client wants to use S3 to share files with people outside the organization. They're currently using S3 IA storage class and manually making a file public when it needs to be accessed. To save costs they want to change the storage class from IA to Glacier after 30 days using lifecycle rules. I think we're going to run into a problem where the files in the IA class (which have no public read permissions upon upload) are going to automatically change to Glacier storage class, and when my client tries to restore the file from Glacier they're not going to be able to get a public URL to the object because of the ACL they were originally uploaded with. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure about console, but you can setup ACL when you do make restore requests using AWS CLI. It must be only AWS console? Can you use AWS CLI or SDK?

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing it in the console. I checked multiple times though. Thanks for the info re: CLI/SDK. We might be able to use the SDK if it's the only option